# Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:badges/badges.dart'

Tags: flutter, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, flutter-dependencies

This is highly unusual, but after adding [the badges package](https://pub.dev/packages/badges/install) to my Flutter project's pubspec.yaml library, I am unable to import the badges package into a file for use.

To add the package I have tried (1) "flutter pub add badges" within my project's root directory, and also (2) "badges: ^3.1.2" and later "badges: ^2.0.3" beneath other package-titles within the pubspec.yaml file, followed by the "pub get button".

[image: badges package added]

Despite Flutter's confirmation of the package being added, the package cannot be added to a file of the project.

To complicate things further, I tried adding the package to a different Flutter project, and there the "badges" package can be added to files.

It seems that within a particular project the badges package isn't working properly.  My question is how can this issue be resolved?

Comment: Terminating Android Studio, restarting it and letting all the data processing for the restart complete made a difference.  After doing this the badges package became accessible for addition to the project's files.

Comment: From file section of Android studio Invalidate caches and restart the studio your problem will be solved..